# SQL Query for Outer Join with Group By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have the **Months** Table with MonthName, MonthNumber and Fiscal Year starts with July so I have assigned the values to the months like

MonthName=July and MonthNumber=1 
MonthName=August and MonthNumber=2.

I have another Domain table **BudgetCategory** and it has BudgetCategoryId, BudgetCategoryName.

The **PurchaseOrder** table has OrderID, PurchaseMonth, BudgetCategoryId.

Now I want the query to find out the Monthly Purchases ***SUM(TotalCost)*** for every BudgetCategory. If there are no purchases for any BudgetCategoryId  I want to display the zero in report.

**Schema of Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BudgetCategory](
[BudgetCategoryId] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[BudgetCategoryName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TotalBudget] [nvarchar](50) NULL)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseOrder](
[OrderId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[BudgetCategoryId] [bigint] NULL,
[PurchaseMonth] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[QTY] [bigint] NULL,
[CostPerItem] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[TotalCost] [decimal](10, 2) NULL)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MonthTable](
[MonthNumber] [bigint] NULL,
[MonthName] [nvarchar](30) NULL)
```

Comment: Monthly Purchases -- what you want to know sum, count, true/false ?

Comment: I want to know the SUM(TotalCost) for every BudgetCategory on Every Month...

Comment: How do you relate Purchase Orders with Month?

Comment: [PurchaseMonth] = 'July', 'August'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*, m.MonthNumber, q.[BudgetCategoryId], q.[PurchaseMonth], ISNULL(q.[TotalCost],0)
FROM [dbo].[BudgetCategory] b
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT [BudgetCategoryId], [PurchaseMonth], sum([TotalCost]) [TotalCost]
        FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] p
        GROUP BY p.[BudgetCategoryId], [PurchaseMonth]
    ) q ON b.BudgetCategoryId = q.BudgetCategoryId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[MonthTable] m ON q.[PurchaseMonth] = m.[MonthName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.BudgetCategoryName,
ISNULL(c.MonthName,'No purchase') as Month,
sum(ISNULL(TotalCost,0)) as TotalCost
from #BudgetCategory a left join #PurchaseOrder b on a.BudgetCategoryId = b.BudgetCategoryId
left join #MonthTable c on b.PurchaseMonth = c.[MonthName]
group by a.BudgetCategoryName,c.MonthName
order by a.BudgetCategoryName
```

Tested with this data

```
INSERT #BudgetCategory
VALUES (1,'CategoryA',1000),
(2,'CategoryB',2000),
(3,'CategoryC',1500),
(4,'CategoryD',2000)

INSERT #PurchaseOrder (OrderId,BudgetCategoryId,TotalCost,PurchaseMonth)
VALUES (1,1,550,'July'),
(2,1,700,'July'),
(3,2,600,'August')

INSERT #MonthTable
VALUES
(1,'July'),
(2,'August')
```

It will produce this results:

[image]

Let me know if this could help you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I want to display Month Name and TotalPurchase for Eevery CategoryId. 

Month        TotalPurchase     BudgetCategory
July              2000                     Category1
August         0                           Category1
August         2000                    Category 2

Comment: you don't need join to MonthTable if you want retrieve MonthName, because you have this value in   [dbo].[PurchaseOrder]

Comment: If there is no purchase for a `CategoryId` then there will not be `PurchaseMonth` in this case the query will show `No Purchase` in month.

Comment: @user2989845, I am suspecting Month table could have several columns that can be useful for user report, I think he just put those columns to explain in short what he needs.